Is the Pauli principle valid outside atomic structures?
The exclusion principle was formulated to explain the structure of atoms and in its original version states that no two electrons in an atom can match in all quantum numbers. They differ at least in the orientation of their spin.
The Pauli principle is now also applied to considerations of free particles, for example in this post Pauli exclusion principle for arbitrarily spacelike separated electrons.. Which experimental observations justify applying the Pauli principle to free particles? And as a side question, for which cases in physics is this applied?

The Pauli's Exclusion Principle is one of those most-widely-tested experimental facts. There are way too many observations justifying its use on all fermions, free or not.

It works in neutron stars...

I don’t know of any fundamental laws of physics that work in some places and not in others.

Yes. Any system of half-integer spin particles must be described by an antisymmetric quantum state with respect to particle permutations. These are fermions, and the antisymmetric requirement leads to the Pauli exclusion principle. Integer-spin particles are bosons, and they must be described by a symmetric state. Bosons are not subject to the exclusion principle.
